# php form to take action against values in a row based on checkbox

Tags: php, form-submit

I have a php page that performs a sql query and presents some data. This data is multiple rows of data, each row is relevant to a particular userid. In the PHP code, i add a checkbox next to each user.

```
        function solist()
    {
        $con = sqlconnect();
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"select members.name, syndicate_sourcebans.sb_srvgroups.name,groups.g_title,sg_servers.server_title from members inner join groups on groups.g_id=members.OrigFGrp left join sg_servers on BIN(sg_servers.server_id)=BIN(members.SOServer) left join syndicate_sourcebans.sb_admins on SteamToInt(syndicate_sourcebans.sb_admins.authid)=members.steamid left join syndicate_sourcebans.sb_srvgroups on syndicate_sourcebans.sb_srvgroups.id=members.origsbgrp where members.member_group_id=17 order by sg_servers.server_title");
        echo "<table><form name='demotions' action='removeso.php' method='post'>
        <tr>
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Original Sourcebans Group</th>
        <th>Original Forum Group</th>
        <th>Assigned Server</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='sodemote'></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Process Demotions'></form></table>";
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

The table populates and the checkmarks appear as expected. Basically, if i checkmark a user (or multiple users) I would like their unique id sent to removeso.php. I've done things like this in ASP but php is very new to me. Any advice on how to accomplish this, or the best resource to self-learn how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is something like this:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='username' value='". $row[id_here] ."'></td>";
```

Have the entire list wrapped up into a form and once you're done, perform a if checked statement and send all data towards removeso.php.

If you want the data to be handle inmediately without having to send the form you'll have to look at Ajax techniques.

Answer (score 1):

In your `input` tag, you need to set a value to be sent to your target page if the box is checked.

So for example;

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sodemote' value'" . $row[0] . "'>";
// Where $row[0] is the value of the id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked too, but user2780711 answered first, thanks!